# Variables in Sqlite using python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to write a code that generates internet browsing history the current day using the chrome history database. This is what I have so far:

```
import datetime

epoch = datetime.date(1601, 1, 1)
day=datetime.date.today()
tdelta=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start= day-epoch
end= day+tdelta-epoch
startSec=int(start.total_seconds())*1000000
endSec=int(end.total_seconds())*1000000

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('c:/Users/Nick/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/History')
cursor = conn.cursor()

print ("Internet history:")
cursor.execute("SELECT url, last_visit_time FROM urls WHERE last_visit_time>='startSec' AND last_visit_time<'endSec'")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

The problem is that my variables startSec and endSec don't seem to be working. However, when I replace those with actual numbers, the code is able to work.

I've attempted to use placeholders too, but that doesn't seem to be working either?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT url, last_visit_time FROM urls WHERE last_visit_time>=%s, (startSec,)) AND last_visit_time<%s, (endSec,))")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your initial query not works becomes clear when you make yourself aware that you are sending this query to SQL. SQL has of course no knowledge of your variables. You also have them in single quotes, so they are treated as string, anways.

`"SELECT url, last_visit_time FROM urls WHERE last_visit_time>='startSec' AND last_visit_time<'endSec'"`

Now, you want to use placeholder which in itself is not a bad idea. There is actually a good way to set this up. Its called parameterized queries. The differece to the placeholder like you want to use them is that you send the query and the variables both the SQL and let SQL evaluate the query and the parameters. This is to ensure the query is not harmful.

If you use normal placeholder in python you fill in the variables in your code and send just a normal query. SQL will not protect you from something called SQL Injection.

The proper way to do it would be to prepare a statement with placeholder symbols. SQLite understands `?` but its more common across other databes to name the parameters like `@p1` `@p2` `@p3` ect.  Depending on your driver sqlite also understands the `@p1` syntax.

```py
sql = "SELECT url, last_visit_time FROM urls WHERE last_visit_time >= ? AND last_visit_time < ?"
args = (startSec, endSec)
cursor = database_connection.execute(sql, args)
```